# Listing all sub-sites that you have access to in a site collection

Tags: permissions, rest, csom, api

In my situation, I have a site collection

```
`/sites/mysitecol` - site collection
  - `/sites/mysitecol/test1` - sub-site - my user has access to this site.
  - `/sites/mysitecol/test2` - sub-site - my user DOES NOT have access to this site.
```

So I'm writing a program that calls the SharePoint rest api and queries for all the /Webs in the site collection.

But because I do not have access to /test2, it gives me a 401-unauthorized when trying to list the /webs.

Is there some way to list the webs such that it only returns the ones my logged-in user has access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [SP.Web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246242(v=office.15))

Here's the example given in the documentation.

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script type="text/ecmascript" language="ecmascript">

    var webCollection = null;
    function runCode() {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
            var web = clientContext.get_web();

            this.webCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);

            clientContext.load(this.webCollection);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var webInfo = 'Child sites of the current site: \n\n';
        var webEnumerator = this.webCollection.getEnumerator();
        while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
            webInfo += web.get_title() + '\n';
        }
        alert(webInfo);
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

</script>

    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Run Code" onclick="runCode()" />

</asp:Content>
```

**Update**:

It appears `getSubwebsForCurrentUser` works with the JavaScript Client Object Model but not with the REST API. For the REST API you need to instead use `getSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser`. I wasn't able to find documentation on this method so I can't provide detailed guidance on the use of the parameters. I was able to get some sample code working.

This code is injected into a web part page using a Content Editor. It was tested in SharePoint Online.

```
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="getSubwebs()">Get Sub Webs</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getSubwebs() {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
      "/_api/Web/getsubwebsfilteredforcurrentuser(nWebTemplateFilter=-1,nConfigurationFilter=-1)";

    var call = jQuery.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }
    });
    call.done(function (data) {
      debugger;
    });
    call.fail(function (jqXHR) {
      alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: yes this sounds like exactly what I need. I'll test it and approve if it works!

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza Please see the update I added to my answer if you're using the SharePoint REST API.

Comment: I'll be using CSOM so if the first approach doesn't work, I'll fallback to the 2nd one

Comment: yeah the csom approach worked fine. (first example).